# Cannot import python-bitcoinlib into a simple script

Tags: python, python-bitcoinlib

Im writing a simple python script to connect to a local bitcoin node and list transactions.

I created a virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv bitcoinenv
```

And then activated:

```
source bitcoinenv/bin/activate
```

The I installed python-bitcoinlib with:

```
pip install python-bitcoinlib
```

I have a simple script:

```
import requests
import bitcoin.rpc

# Connect to the local Bitcoin node
connection = bitcoin.rpc.Proxy()

# Get a list of unspent transactions
unspent_transactions = connection.listunspent()

# Print the unspent transactions
print(unspent_transactions)
```

And I run this with:

```
python bitcoin.py
```

But I get the error:

```
import bitcoin.rpc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoin.rpc'; 'bitcoin' is not a package
```

Heres more information about my environment. When I run:

```
which python
```

I get:

```
/Users/me/Bitcoin/exchange/bitcoinenv/bin/python
```

When I run:

```
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

I get:

```
/Users/me/Bitcoin/exchange/bitcoinenv
```

When I go to `/Users/me/Bitcoin/exchange/bitcoinenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and list the contents I see:

[image]

When I run `pip --version` I get:

```
pip 22.3.1 from /Users/me/Bitcoin/exchange/bitcoinenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

And when I run `python --version` I get:

```
Python 3.8.0
```

Has anyone any idea why I cant import the python-bitcoinlib library?